# Android app crashes when filling array list with name of audio files in SD card?

Tags: java, android, listview

So I am working on an application that has 3 tabs with swipe gestures enabled. The tab containing content for playlists is actually a `ListFragment`. I am trying to read the names of all the audio files on my SD card and then fill a list with them.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.stupidmusicplayer.application" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**This is the code for Adapter**

```java
package com.example.stupidmusicplayer.application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class playlistArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final String[]  artistarray;
private final ArrayList<String> songarray;

public playlistArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList songnames, String[] artistnames) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_layout, songnames);
    this.context = context;
    songarray = songnames;
    artistarray = artistnames;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
    TextView songName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView artistName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

    //set text for text1 here
    songName.setText(songarray.get(position));

    // set text for text2 here
    artistName.setText(artistarray[position]);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

**and this is the code in the `ListFragment`**

```java
public class playlist extends ListFragment {

public ArrayList<String> songarray;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    findAllMusicFiles();

    String artistarray[] = new String[]{
            //Random data as an example in the array...
    };

    playlistArrayAdapter adapter = new playlistArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), songarray, artistarray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
    //The code to fill arraylist with audio file names.
public void findAllMusicFiles() {

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        while (audioCursor.moveToNext()) {
              songarray.add(audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        }
        audioCursor.close();
    }
}

}
```

If i replace the entire `ArrayList` code with just a simple array with some data it works but when i try to bring in the list, it crashes.

**ADB Logs say**

> ddms: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:698)
>       at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
>       at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)"

AND

> ddms: Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger

Comment: P.S. It's a good idea to use `PascalCase` for naming Java classes vs `camelCase`.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method within the ListFragment, you are first calling findAllMusicFiles() which tries to do an add() to the songArray.  However, I don't see anywhere that you are instantiating the songArray.  Notice how you setup the artistArray in onCreate just after the call to finAllMusicFiles().  You need to do something similar for the song array somewhere and I'm not seeing where that is.

The only other reference is to set songArray to songNames, but I don't see any guarantee that songNames has been set up either.  You are getting a NullPointerException because songArray needs to be instantiated before you try to manipulate it in any way.

Comment: ThankYou @blh83
so i just add this
songarray = new ArrayList<String>();
right before where i call findAllMusicFiles() ?

Comment: I believe that would help, yes.

Comment: Okaay your suggestion solved the first problem. But now when i scroll the list view the app crashes? Any suggestions?

Comment: should i add scroll view or something?

Comment: If you can, please post the adb output for the new crash and I can take a look a bit later.  thanks.